# SQL: Incorrect syntax near ')' Must not save data between the time range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error when I add this query:

```
OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST('" & start.SelectedValue & "' AS DATETIME),108) <=  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-in], 108) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST('" & ends.SelectedValue & "' AS DATETIME), 108)  >=   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-out], 108)
```

This is the whole query:

```
 Dim SQL5 = New SqlCommand("SELECT Room, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-in], 108) AS [Time-in], CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-out], 108) as [Time-out] FROM [RS].[dbo].[Time] WHERE CAST([Reserve_date] AS DATE) = CAST('" & Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AS DATE) AND Room = ('" & roomType.SelectedValue & "' )                          AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST('" & start.SelectedValue & "' AS DATETIME),108) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-in], 108) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-out], 108)                                                                                                       OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST('" & start.SelectedValue & "' AS DATETIME),108) <=  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-in], 108) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST('" & ends.SelectedValue & "' AS DATETIME), 108)  >=   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-out], 108)                                                                                                                                                              OR CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST('" & ends.SelectedValue & "' AS DATETIME), 108) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-in], 108) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-out], 108))", connection)
```

Comment: You have an extra or missing opening or closing parenthesis, or a string is not quoted properly.

Comment: `(` before `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST('" & start.SelectedValue` is not closed properly

Comment: *print* the complete constructed query before (or instead of) trying to execute it. Being able to locate unbalanced parentheses is a skill you should acquire rather than expecting other people to do it for you. Also, don't just fix the parenthesis issue and move on. Go and learn about SQL injection and why you absolutely should be using parameters rather than string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Are missing a ) at the End

```
OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST('" & start.SelectedValue & "' AS DATETIME), 108) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-in], 108)
          AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST('" & ends.SelectedValue & "' AS DATETIME), 108) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time-out], 108)
);--Add one more ) Here
```

Comment: Because you are missing the ) for the First (